# Get one database record, display it, update it, and save it back to the database

Tags: breeze

SOLVED! It was a Knockout issue (wrong binding). But maybe someone likes to argue or comment about the code in general (dataservice, viewmodel, etc).

I tried to build a Breeze sample, where I get one database record (with **fetchEntityByKey**), display it for updating, then with a save button, write the changes back to the database. I could not figure out how to get it to work.

I was trying to have a **dataservice** ('class') and a **viewmodel** ('class'), binding the viewmodel with Knockout to the view.

I very much appreciated if someone could provide a sample or provide some hints.

Thankx, Harry

```
 var dataservice = (function () {
     var serviceName = "/api/amms/";
     breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
     var entityManager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);

     var dataservice = {
         serviceName: serviceName,
         entityManager: entityManager,
         init: init,
         saveChanges: saveChanges,
         getLocation: getLocation
     };

     return dataservice;

     function init() {
         return getMetadataStore();
     }

     function getMetadataStore() {
         return entityManager.fetchMetadata()
             .then(function (result) { return dataservice; })
             .fail(function () { window.alert("fetchMetadata:fail"); })
             .fin(function () { });
     }

     function saveChanges() {
         return entityManager.saveChanges()
             .then(function (result) { return result; })
             .fail(function () { window.alert("fetchEntityByKey:fail"); })
             .fin(function () { });
     }

     function getLocation() {
         return entityManager.fetchEntityByKey("LgtLocation", 1001, false)
             .then(function (result) { return result.entity; })
             .fail(function () { window.alert("fetchEntityByKey:fail"); })
             .fin(function () { });
     }
 })();

 var viewmodel = (function () {
     var viewmodel = {
         location: null,
         error: ko.observable(""),
         init: init,
         saveChanges: null
     };

     return viewmodel;

     function init() {
         return dataservice.init().then(function () {
             viewmodel.saveChanges = dataservice.saveChanges;
             return getLocation();
         })
     }

     function getLocation() {
         return dataservice.getLocation().then(function (result) {
             return viewmodel.location = result;
         })
     }
 })();

 viewmodel.init().then(function () {
     ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
 });
```

Comment: Could you paste a code sample? Are you getting an error from the call to saveChanges?

Comment: Hi Richard... I have added the code above. No I do not get a error from the call to saveChanges

Comment: Hi Richard... It was not a coding issue from Breeze, I did something wrong with Knockout. Maybe you would like to comment on the code above... Thankx!

Answer (score 0):

Glad you solved it. Can't help noticing that you added a great number of do-nothing callbacks. I can't think of a reason to do that. You also asked for metadata explicitly. But your call to `fetchEntityByKey` will do that implicitly for you because, **as you called it**, it will always go to the server.

Also, it is a good idea to re-throw the error in the fail callback within a dataservice so that a caller (e.g., the ViewModel) can add its own fail handler. Without re-throw, the caller's fail callback would not hear it (Q promise machinery acts as if the first fail handler "solved" the problem).

Therefore, your dataservice could be reduced to:

```
 var dataservice = (function () {
     breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
     var serviceName = "/api/amms/";
     var entityManager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);

     var dataservice = {
         serviceName: serviceName,     // why are you exporting this?
         entityManager: entityManager,
         saveChanges: saveChanges,
         getLocation: getLocation
     };

     return dataservice;

     function saveChanges() {
         return entityManager.saveChanges()
             .fail(function () { 
                 window.alert("saveChanges failed: " + error.message);
                 throw error; // re-throw so caller can hear it
             })
     }

     function getLocation() {
         return entityManager.fetchEntityByKey("LgtLocation", 1001, false)
             .then(function (result) { return result.entity; })
             .fail(function () { 
                 window.alert("fetchEntityByKey failed: " + error.message);
                 throw error; // re-throw so caller can hear it
             })
     }
 })();
```

I don't want to make too much of this. Maybe you're giving us the stripped down version of something more substantial. But, in case you (or a reader) think those methods are always necessary, I wanted to make clear that they are not.